# Does Lightning Bolt affect everyone in its line of effect?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, line-of-effect

I'm looking for clarification on a spell effect. The specific spell in question is *lightning bolt*, 3rd-level Sorcerer/Wizard spell. It has an area of a 120-ft line. Does it pass through enemies? If I have 4 enemies in a line in range, does it hit all, or only the first? I saw [Do enemies block line of effect?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6980/do-enemies-block-line-of-effect),
but that only helped for 4e, this is PF which has different wording.

So does an enemy count as a "Solid Barrier" for the purpose of blocking the effect from going further? Any info is appreciated, especially if you can point me to a source I can reference in the future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes, *lightning bolt* affects everyone in its line of effect

#### Creatures do not block line-of-effect, so areas extend through them

A line area effect targets all squares (within the limits of its range and shape) to which the effect has line-of-effect.

<sub>[Magic Overview > Aiming a Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) > Area > Cone, Cylinder, Line, or Sphere</sub>

> A line-shaped spell shoots away from you in a line in the direction you designate. It starts from any corner of your square and extends to the limit of its range **or until it strikes a barrier that blocks line of effect.**

Note that, in the absence of such a blocker,

> A line-shaped spell affects all creatures in squares through which the line passes.

So already there is a notion that multiple creatures can be included in the area, implying that they do not block the effect. But we can do better than an implication.

<sub>[Glossary > Line of Effect](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Line-of-Effect)</sub>

> A line of effect is a straight, unblocked path that indicates what a spell can affect. A line of effect is canceled by a solid barrier. It's like line of sight for ranged weapons, except that it's not blocked by fog, darkness, and other factors that limit normal sight. A line of effect starts from any corner of your square and extends to the limit of its range or until it strikes a barrier that would block it. A line-shaped spell affects all creatures in squares through which the line passes.

Here we have the text explicitly stating that the line of effect passes through creatures. A creature is therefore not a solid barrier.

Comment: That was fast. Thank you very much for the quick and succint clarification. I assumed that was how it was supposed to act, and was going to Rule 0 it for balance if not, but wanted to be 100% sure first. Thank you again, I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 9):

[Lightning Bolt](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/lightningBolt.html#lightning-bolt) is has an area of effect; 'line'.

From the [CRB chapter on Magic](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magic.html):

> A line-shaped spell shoots away from you in a line in the direction you designate. It starts from any corner of your square and extends to the limit of its range or until it strikes a barrier that blocks **line of effect**. A line-shaped spell affects all creatures in squares through which the line passes.

The implication from the final line, is that yes a line shaped spell passes through creatures.

From the [CRB](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/combat.html) chapter on Combat, wrt Total Cover:

> Total Cover: If you don't have line of effect to your target (that is, you cannot draw any line from your square to your target's square without crossing a solid barrier), he is considered to have total cover from you. You can't make an attack against a target that has total cover.

So Total Cover is defined as a lack of line of effect.

But a creature only provides soft cover:

> Soft Cover: Creatures, even your enemies, can provide you with cover against ranged attacks, giving you a +4 bonus to AC. However, such soft cover provides no bonus on Reflex saves, nor does soft cover allow you to make a Stealth check.

So by the Cover rules, yes your line spell will pass through creatures as they do not provide total cover.